# Cannot get included js file in the Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, static

I have a simples pure Node.js app. Its structure looks like this:

[image]

```
The problem is I cannot get common.js properly.
The app.mjs consists of:
import http from 'http'
import fs from 'fs'
import nStatic from 'node-static'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import debug from 'debug'

const output = debug('app')

const fileServer = new nStatic.Server('./public')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fileServer.serve(req, res)
  const Url = new URL(req.url, 'http://localhost:3000/')
  const fileExt = Url.pathname.split('/').pop().split('.').pop()
  let aType = ''

  switch (fileExt) {
    case 'ico':
      aType = 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'
      break
    case 'js':
      aType = 'application/javascript'
      break
    case 'json':
      aType = 'application/json'
      break
    default:
      aType = 'text/html'
      break
  }
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': aType })

  const filePath = 'views/node.html'
  // using readFile
  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error has occured: ', err)
      res.end(content)
    } else {
      res.end(content)
    }
  })
})

server.listen(3000, () => output(`Listen to me ${chalk.green('3000')}`))
```

After launching it can find `common.js`

[image]

but returns the contents of `views/index.html` instead of the script itself:

[image]

`common.js`:

```
console.log('Common js here to help!')
```

Also it outputs errors:
[image]
So, supposedly this is something simple, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are serving the same file on every request. 
These lines will always respond with the contents of the file "node.html".

```
const filePath = 'views/node.html'
fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
      res.end(content)
});
```

According to node-static [documentation](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static#serving-files-under-a-directory) a correct way to serve a directory would be:

```
const http = require('http');
const NodeStatic = require('node-static');

const fileServer = new NodeStatic.Server('./public');

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
});
server.listen(8080);
```